# Каким образом считать данные из JTextField в переменную класса типа int?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

У меня есть JFrame, на котором размещено JTextField с пустым значением, и есть переменная класса типа int без инициализации (или автоматическая инициализация её нулем).

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setColumns(6);
frame.add(textField);
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы когда пользователь внесет свое значение в JTextField на открывшемся окне, оно было записано в переменную типа int, и со значением этой переменной можно было бы работать далее в программе?

Если я пытаюсь ставить  запись через слушатель, то ничего в переменную не записывается (скорее всего сам слушатель не срабатывает):

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String getValue = textField.getText();
                x = Integer.parseInt(getValue); // x - переменная класса, в которую нужно записать значение введенное пользователем
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь условие при котором слушатель будет срабатывать.
К примеру добавь кнопку.
Например :

```
If(e.getSource()==button){
String getValue = textField.getText();
x = Integer.parseInt(getValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

с помощью кнопки можно взять значение из текстового поля.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //Берем значение вводимое пользователем
            String s = inputNumber.getText();
            //Присваиваем его переменной класса
             i = Integer.parseInt(s);
             //Используем - Например вставляем в другое текстовое поле
           testNumber.setText(String.valueOf(i));

        }
    });
```